# How to forcefully fetch key-value from iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud

In my application I am storing username and password in iCloud key value store. On first launch I am calling synchronize to fetch data from iCLoud but there is a delay. Is there any way to forcefully fetch the data in iCloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do this by setting a fake iCloud key-value immediately after initialization, like:

```
    NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore *kvStore = [NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore];
    [kvStore setObject:@"th" forKey:@"KVTickle"];
```